# find package Cpp-netlib

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries, cpp-netlib

I am trying to link against `cppnetlib-0.9.4`  ,but I don't know what `argument` to pass to `find_package` in `CMake` for using the libraries?

Comment: [How To Find Libraries](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries).

Comment: I have added my libcppnetlib-client-connections.a ,libcppnetlib-server-parsers.a and libcppnetlib-uri.a   to /usr/lib in my cmake I have find_package(Boost REQUIRED date_time system filesystem thread regex serialization wserialization program_options)

Comment: now what name I should add to find_packege(),as I seen if library name is libboost_regex.a ,the cmake contains find_packege(Boost  REQUIRED regex); what it will be in my case?